# Trying to generate custom play button for SoundCloud API

Tags: radio-button, toggle, soundcloud, elementor

I was experimenting with SoundCloud API in Elementor, but I couldn't solve a problem because I have very little knowledge about JS. I was trying to achieve custom play/stop button.

1. I added a play icon, which changes to a stop icon
2. It started playing as it should be, but now it's not stopping.

So when I click the icon with the id of **#playBPP** works well but when I click to the button again it's not working.

**This is where I added JS.**

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- SoundCloud-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Play - Stop
    $(function(){
      var widget1 = SC.Widget("bppRadioPlayer");
        $("#playBPP").click(function() {
          widget1.play();
      });  
      $("toggle-pause").click(function() {
          widget1.pause();
      });      
    });
    
    // Audio button toggle
    const audioButton = document.querySelector('.audio-button');
        audioButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        audioButton.classList.toggle('toggle-pause');
    });
    
    
  </script> 

<iframe id="bppRadioPlayer" width="100%" height="160" scrolling="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/sdyld/bpp-bonvoyage" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

**Icon HTML**

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-ff4607e audio-button elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="ff4607e" data-element_type="widget" id="playBPP" data-widget_type="icon.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
      <div class="elementor-icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-play"></i> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.toggle-pause .elementor-icon i::before{
    content: '\f04c';

}
```

[check out the page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjhsY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the snippet to achieve the goal, dropping here, so you can use.

```js
var SC = "object" == typeof SC ? SC : {};
SC.Widget = function(e) {
  var t = {};

  function n(r) {
    if (t[r]) return t[r].exports;
    var o = t[r] = {
      i: r,
      l: !1,
      exports: {}
    };
    return e[r].call(o.exports, o, o.exports, n), o.l = !0, o.exports
  }
  return n.m = e, n.c = t, n.d = function(e, t, r) {
    n.o(e, t) || Object.defineProperty(e, t, {
      enumerable: !0,
      get: r
    })
  }, n.r = function(e) {
    "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
      value: "Module"
    }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    })
  }, n.t = function(e, t) {
    if (1 & t && (e = n(e)), 8 & t) return e;
    if (4 & t && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
    var r = Object.create(null);
    if (n.r(r), Object.defineProperty(r, "default", {
        enumerable: !0,
        value: e
      }), 2 & t && "string" != typeof e)
      for (var o in e) n.d(r, o, function(t) {
        return e[t]
      }.bind(null, o));
    return r
  }, n.n = function(e) {
    var t = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
      return e.default
    } : function() {
      return e
    };
    return n.d(t, "a", t), t
  }, n.o = function(e, t) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t)
  }, n.p = "", n(n.s = 0)
}([function(e, t, n) {
  var r, o, i, u = n(1),
    a = n(2),
    c = n(3),
    s = u.api,
    l = u.bridge,
    d = [],
    f = [],
    p = /^http(?:s?)/;

  function E(e) {
    var t, n;
    for (t = 0, n = f.length; t < n && !1 !== e(f[t]); t++);
  }

  function v(e) {
    return e.contentWindow ? e.contentWindow : e.contentDocument && "parentWindow" in e.contentDocument ? e.contentDocument.parentWindow : null
  }

  function _(e) {
    var t, n = [];
    for (t in e) e.hasOwnProperty(t) && n.push(e[t]);
    return n
  }

  function S(e, t, n) {
    n.callbacks[e] = n.callbacks[e] || [], n.callbacks[e].push(t)
  }

  function h(e, t) {
    var n = !0;
    return t.callbacks[e] = [], E((function(t) {
      if ((t.callbacks[e] || []).length) return n = !1, !1
    })), n
  }

  function y(e, t, n) {
    var r, o, i = v(n);
    if (!i.postMessage) return !1;
    r = n.getAttribute("src").split("?")[0], o = JSON.stringify({
      method: e,
      value: t
    }), "//" === r.substr(0, 2) && (r = window.location.protocol + r), r = r.replace(/http:\/\/(w|wt).soundcloud.com/, "https://$1.soundcloud.com"), i.postMessage(o, r)
  }

  function b(e) {
    var t;
    return E((function(n) {
      if (n.instance === e) return t = n, !1
    })), t
  }

  function g(e) {
    var t;
    return E((function(n) {
      if (v(n.element) === e) return t = n, !1
    })), t
  }

  function m(e, t) {
    return function(n) {
      var r, o = !!((r = n) && r.constructor && r.call && r.apply),
        i = b(this),
        u = !o && t ? n : null,
        a = o && !t ? n : null;
      return a && S(e, a, i), y(e, u, i.element), this
    }
  }

  function R(e, t, n) {
    var r, o, i;
    for (r = 0, o = t.length; r < o; r++) e[i = t[r]] = m(i, n)
  }

  function O(e, t, n) {
    return e + "?url=" + t + "&" + function(e) {
      var t, n, r = [];
      for (t in e) e.hasOwnProperty(t) && (n = e[t], r.push(t + "=" + ("start_track" === t ? parseInt(n, 10) : n ? "true" : "false")));
      return r.join("&")
    }(n)
  }

  function w(e, t, n) {
    var r, o, i = e.callbacks[t] || [];
    for (r = 0, o = i.length; r < o; r++) i[r].apply(e.instance, n);
    (function(e) {
      var t, n = !1;
      for (t in a)
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(t) && a[t] === e) {
          n = !0;
          break
        } return n
    }(t) || t === s.READY) && (e.callbacks[t] = [])
  }

  function A(e) {
    var t, n, r, o, i;
    try {
      n = JSON.parse(e.data)
    } catch (e) {
      return !1
    }
    return t = g(e.source), r = n.method, o = n.value, (!t || P(e.origin) === P(t.domain)) && (t ? (r === s.READY && (t.isReady = !0, w(t, "__LATE_BINDING__"), h("__LATE_BINDING__", t)), r !== s.PLAY || t.playEventFired || (t.playEventFired = !0), r !== s.PLAY_PROGRESS || t.playEventFired || (t.playEventFired = !0, w(t, s.PLAY, [o])), i = [], void 0 !== o && i.push(o), void w(t, r, i)) : (r === s.READY && d.push(e.source), !1))
  }

  function P(e) {
    return e.replace(p, "")
  }
  window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("message", A, !1) : window.attachEvent("onmessage", A), e.exports = i = function(e, t, n) {
    var i;
    if (("" === (i = e) || i && i.charCodeAt && i.substr) && (e = document.getElementById(e)), ! function(e) {
        return !(!e || 1 !== e.nodeType || "IFRAME" !== e.nodeName.toUpperCase())
      }(e)) throw new Error("SC.Widget function should be given either iframe element or a string specifying id attribute of iframe element.");
    t && (n = n || {}, e.src = O("http://wt.soundcloud.test:9200/", t, n));
    var u, a, c = g(v(e));
    return c && c.instance ? c.instance : (u = d.indexOf(v(e)) > -1, a = new r(e), f.push(new o(a, e, u)), a)
  }, i.Events = s, window.SC = window.SC || {}, window.SC.Widget = i, o = function(e, t, n) {
    this.instance = e, this.element = t, this.domain = function(e) {
      var t, n, r, o = "";
      "//" === e.substr(0, 2) && (e = window.location.protocol + e);
      for (r = e.split("/"), t = 0, n = r.length; t < n && t < 3; t++) o += r[t], t < 2 && (o += "/");
      return o
    }(t.getAttribute("src")), this.isReady = !!n, this.callbacks = {}
  }, (r = function() {}).prototype = {
    constructor: r,
    load: function(e, t) {
      if (e) {
        t = t || {};
        var n = this,
          r = b(this),
          o = r.element,
          i = o.src,
          u = i.substr(0, i.indexOf("?"));
        r.isReady = !1, r.playEventFired = !1, o.onload = function() {
          n.bind(s.READY, (function() {
            var e, n = r.callbacks;
            for (e in n) n.hasOwnProperty(e) && e !== s.READY && y(l.ADD_LISTENER, e, r.element);
            t.callback && t.callback()
          }))
        }, o.src = O(u, e, t)
      }
    },
    bind: function(e, t) {
      var n = this,
        r = b(this);
      return r && r.element && (e === s.READY && r.isReady ? setTimeout(t, 1) : r.isReady ? (S(e, t, r), y(l.ADD_LISTENER, e, r.element)) : S("__LATE_BINDING__", (function() {
        n.bind(e, t)
      }), r)), this
    },
    unbind: function(e) {
      var t, n = b(this);
      n && n.element && (t = h(e, n), e !== s.READY && t && y(l.REMOVE_LISTENER, e, n.element))
    }
  }, R(r.prototype, _(a)), R(r.prototype, _(c), !0)
}, function(e, t) {
  t.api = {
    LOAD_PROGRESS: "loadProgress",
    PLAY_PROGRESS: "playProgress",
    PLAY: "play",
    PAUSE: "pause",
    FINISH: "finish",
    SEEK: "seek",
    READY: "ready",
    OPEN_SHARE_PANEL: "sharePanelOpened",
    CLICK_DOWNLOAD: "downloadClicked",
    CLICK_BUY: "buyClicked",
    ERROR: "error"
  }, t.bridge = {
    REMOVE_LISTENER: "removeEventListener",
    ADD_LISTENER: "addEventListener"
  }
}, function(e, t) {
  e.exports = {
    GET_VOLUME: "getVolume",
    GET_DURATION: "getDuration",
    GET_POSITION: "getPosition",
    GET_SOUNDS: "getSounds",
    GET_CURRENT_SOUND: "getCurrentSound",
    GET_CURRENT_SOUND_INDEX: "getCurrentSoundIndex",
    IS_PAUSED: "isPaused"
  }
}, function(e, t) {
  e.exports = {
    PLAY: "play",
    PAUSE: "pause",
    TOGGLE: "toggle",
    SEEK_TO: "seekTo",
    SET_VOLUME: "setVolume",
    NEXT: "next",
    PREV: "prev",
    SKIP: "skip"
  }
}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=http://ent/web-sourcemaps/api.js-27d0ec1de3c5.map

const widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('track'));
const playBtn = document.getElementById("playRadio");

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  widget.toggle();
});

function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-stop");
}

widget.getCurrentSoundIndex(function(sound) {
  console.log(sound.title);
});
```

```css
#playRadio {
  font-size: 72px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

   <head>
     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0b1431f7fb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>

   <body>

     <i id="playRadio" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fas fa-play"></i>
    

     <iframe id="track" width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/249593158&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>



   </body>

 </html>
```